# Large data entry pages using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a large data entry page using the default ASP.NET MVC theme. Due to the large number of controls on the page it would be good to use a two column fieldset so the user does not need to scroll. I can't see any templates in the MVC design gallery that use a two column data entry page, they are all geared towards standard website designs. Has anyone seen any? It would be great to have templates for different data entry scenarios.

Thanks

Danny

Comment: This is more like a xhtml/css question, than asp.net-mvc.
What exactly do you mean by two column data entry? Two fields on one line or label and field on the same line?

Comment: In my case I was thinking two fields on one line. But there are many different ways to layout data entry pages. My point, was it would be good to have different data entry layouts listed in the ASP.NET MVC gallery to help developers building web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create your own T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) file.  You can find out more [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx).  This will give you an extra view content option in your "Add View" dialog box, generating the HTML however you've specified.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of web design templates, but geared towards large data entry layouts. This would help developers who are not that great at layouts. A nice place for these would be in the ASP.NET MVC gallery.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to show all controls on single window without scrolling and may be using two columns,Right!

I have another solution for you. 
And that is Wizard. check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771788/how-do-i-create-a-mvc-wizard-similar-in-functionality-to-webforms-wizards) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297148/how-to-make-a-wizard-with-asp-net-mvc).

Your form will look nice!

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is layout, you can lay it out in the design view first (or dreamweaver or the designer of your choice) then add the MVC specific code.